# OpenSSL issues in Debian Wheezy

Tags: ssl, openssl, curl, debian-wheezy

I don't know what is exactly going on but I noticed that curl couldn't get secure pages without adding extra switches.

```
~# curl -v https://api.dreamhost.com
* About to connect() to api.dreamhost.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 75.119.208.14...
* connected
* Connected to api.dreamhost.com (75.119.208.14) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
(hangs for a minute)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.dreamhost.com:443
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.dreamhost.com:443
```

Now, when I add -1 (force tlsv1) or -3 (force sslv3) curl works flawlessly. The problem is that other programs seem to have similar issues, like python scripts.

When I try openssl it hangs like curl

```
openssl s_client  -connect api.dreamhost.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
(HANGS)

write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

The same happens if I use -tls1_2, but it works If I use -ssl3 switch

Additional Data:

```
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

Does anybody know how to fix this and make curl or openssl work with default settings? I have another machine with Debian lenny that can run both commands flawlessly without any switch.

Thanks!

-Rodrigo

Comment: I have the same result as you with `curl`, `wget` works here though, what do you get with `wget`?

Comment: @EightBitTony wget seems to work well, but also I discovered that other hosts work.
curl https://graph.facebook.com works well without any switched but curl to https://api.dreamhost.com will only work if I use curl -1 or -3

Comment: I wonder if it's something in the auto-detection of which SSL version to use that wget gets right and curl gets wrong?  Anyway, out of my league, good luck!

Comment: Same problem same site, I wonder if Dreamhost is aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this site against [SSLLabs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), you'll see it's [intolerant to long handshakes](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance), a problem that certainly affects your version of OpenSSL.

Reducing the cipher list size should help, for example:

```
openssl s_client -cipher RSA -connect api.dreamhost.com:443
```

(You can use the `--ciphers` option for `curl`.)

Answer (score 1):

So I went ahead and filed a ticket with Dreamhost (Based on the analysis of @Bruno above) because I was having the same issue.  It took a few weeks but they actually fixed it.  Any other company they probably would have just put me in tech support hell.

Comment: can you give information about how dreamhost fixed the issue ? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `ca-certificates` package installed properly. If it is installed, you may have accidentally deleted its files and need to reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Comment: Still the same :/ keeps working when I use -1/-3 switch on curl, or -ssl3 switch for openssl command.

Comment: The CA certificates are only used to verify the remote certificate. Unfortunately, there's no remote certificate presented here at all, so that wouldn't help ("*no peer certificate available*").